# How to fetch record from mysql in sencha touch 2

Tags: sencha-touch

I am new to Sencha touch. I need to fetch record from mysql database and show it on the screen.I I have read the documentation of sencha,but I dnt understand most of it.
Please help me. 
Information in detail will be very helpful.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Sencha touch is JS framework which doesn't come with Database drivers so you cannot connect to Db from it(BTW even if it comes with that I would not recommend connecting mobile devices to my database). So if you need to talk to database you have to have a proxy/controller layer (in Java/php or any other technology you like) which will connect to Db on one end and expose http interface on the other end through which sencha touch app will communicate.

Best practice is to write a Restful service and use your app to communicate through it. Do google search for "How to create rest web service" if you don't know that already.